# Random numbers in a range

Tags: delphi, random, numbers, range

This is in Delphi (7 to be exact). How can I generate random numbers within a specific range? Similar to `random.randint(1,6)` in Python. I'm trying to simulate rolling dice. The other option is to somehow exclude 0.

Currently I have:

```
Randomize;
Roll := Random(7);
Label3.Caption := IntToStr(Roll);
```

Comment: It is trivial to 'somehow' exclude zero. Just do `Random(6) + 1`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use

```
RandomRange(1, 7)
```

which will return a random integer from the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.

(`uses Math`)

[By the way, it is trivial to 'somehow' exclude zero. Just do `Random(6) + 1`.]

Comment: Thanks, but it has to be RandomRange(1,7) so that the 6 is included.

Comment: @Aaron: Yes, I changed that several minutes ago!

Answer (score 2):

Also, it is possible to generate a value from a float range [a, b), exluding b:

```
r := random;
x := (b-a)*r + a;
```

The first line generates a value from [0; 1) interval; the second one gives a value from [a, b).

If you want to get N random values within interval [a; b] (for example, 5 random values from interval [1; 2]: {1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2}) use the following:

```
r := RandomRange(0, N-1);
x := a + r*(b-a)/(N-1);
```

Comment: It should be `RandomRange(0, N)`

Answer (score 1):

to a specific value you may use

```
randomize;
ran:=random(6)+1;
```

that value will randomize between 1 to 6